# file format not supported error in react native image To pdf and react native view shot

Tags: javascript, react-native, pdf, react-native-view-shot

I have take image of screen view in by using view shot library. and after that I convert that image to pdf using react-native-image-to-pdf library.
file saved successfully but. when I try to open that file its saying file format not supported. and also it has no .pdf extension. please help.

here is my state

```
 this.state = {
      imagePath: "",
      pdf: "",
    };
```

here is my function

```
 onCapture = (uri) => {
    console.log("do something with ", uri);
    this.setState({ imagePath: uri.replace("file://", "") });
    console.log("this is " + this.state.imagePath);
  };
 

imageToPdf = async () => {
    try {
      const options = {
        imagePaths: [this.state.imagePath],
        name: "TablePdf" + ".pdf",
        maxSize: {         
          width: 900,
        },
        quality: 0.7,
      };
      const pdf = await RNImageToPdf.createPDFbyImages(options);
      this.setState({ pdf: pdf.filePath });

      Linking.openURL(
        `mailto:support@example.com?subject=SendMail&body=${this.state.pdf}`
      );

      console.log(pdf.filePath);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

here is my View Shot and Entire View

```
   <ScrollView>
    <IconShare onPress={this.imageToPdf}/>
        <ViewShot
            onCapture={this.onCapture}
            captureMode="mount"
            options={{ format: "png", quality: 0.9 }}
            >

         <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
            <View></View>
            <View></View>
            <View></View>
            <View></View>
            <View></View>
            <View></View>
            <View></View>
            <View></View>
            <View></View>
         </ScrollView>

        </ViewShot>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've already tried.

Comment: please check now... I have updated Code

Comment: Thank you. What does `console.log("this is " + this.state.imagePath)` log and what's the output when you do `console.log(pdf.filePath);`

Comment: for this.state.imagePtath === /data/user/0/com.medicare/cache/ReactNative-snapshot-image3689159755902100299.png.   ,   for pdf.filePath === /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.medicare/files/TablePdf.pdf

Comment: You can write the file name as one string instead of concatinating it with a plus sign. Try to rename the resulting file that it has the file extension .pdf. What happens if you open it now?

Comment: then its opening but showing blank black screen

Comment: Okay, so the file is indeed broken. I haven't used react-native-image-to-pdf but it looks like it might have a bug.

Comment: ok so.. is thier any solution on this

Comment: I don't know. Can you open the image?

Comment: I have Table data on my screen. I made that table using just View and Text. I Just want to send that table data as it is in table format to email. or on message... in pdf or docx file

Comment: no. image not opening I dont see any image

Comment: Maybe the image is already broken. That might be why the pdf is broken as well. Have you tried another library yet?

Comment: no I dont try any library other than this two. if there is another library please tell me.

Comment: I don't know any specifically for react native. But maybe someone else does